# Selenium can't load text from element after upgrading firefox from 108 to 109

Tags: selenium-firefoxdriver

I trying to fix selenium test for my application. At some point in time they started to fail on firefox driver.
Test are checking if element has proper text. Now this method is returning empty string, not expected text attached to element but in browser everything is looking ok.

```
fun findElement(selector: By): WebElement {
        waitUntilElementIsVisible(selector)
        return webDriver.findElement(selector).text
    }


fun isElementPresent(selector: By): Boolean {
        return webDriver.findElements(selector)
                .isNotEmpty()
}
```

I tried to change driver to chrome, they are passing.
I chacked every version of firefox from 95 to 110 and that they are starting to failing in version 109.
I check dev changelogs but I couldn't find any possible reason why. I tried to retrieve "innerHtml" and it has correct value.
I want to know why its not working and how to improve my code to work with firefox 109+